# How to determine the mean duration of YouTube videos for specific search term?

Tags: youtube, web-scraping, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know YouTube is very closed and doesn't publish any detailed statistics, but I have a specific research interest to find out the length of arbitrary How-To videos.

When I search for that term I will get a few million results. Would it be possible to determine the playback duration for portions of the search results? Since the usage of the YouTube API is limited one could grasp a few videos per day and maybe with multiple API-keys.

Beside using the API there might be powerful scrapers I could use.

Answer (score 1):

## JS browser utility

I'd recommend you a simple JS utility to use in a browser dev tools. Read [here](https://webscraping.pro/dom-elements-number-counter-and-sum-up/) how to use it for counting. I've modified it to count video length time.

### The JavaScript code

So open a youtube search page and open your browser’s Dev tools (it’s F12 on PCs, Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop menu on Mac). Once they are open, go to Console (Console tab) and enter the following code:

```
function domCounter(selector){
var a = document.querySelectorAll(selector); 
var hour = 0, min = 0;
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++){ 
    var time = a[i].innerHTML.split(':');        
    // console.log(time); 
    hour += parseInt(time[0]);  
    min += parseInt(time[1]);    
    }
return hour + Math.round(min/60);
}
```

### How to find *css* selector

[image]

So to call it in a browser console you just hit:

```
domCounter('span.video-time')
```

### Disclaimer

This utility works for one search page result though. You might get improve it to traverse pagination.

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver, ok I'll.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the duration videos returned from the search endpoint without looking at the video duration for each one.

The search endpoint does, however, provide [`videoDuration`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoDuration) parameter you can pass in to your request to only return videos of a specific duration range:

> The videoDuration parameter filters video search results based on
>   their duration. If you specify a value for this parameter, you must
>   also set the type parameter's value to video.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - `any` – Do not filter video search results based on their duration. This is the default value.
> - `long` – Only include videos longer than 20 minutes. medium – Only include videos that are between four and 20 minutes long (inclusive).
> - `short` – Only include videos that are less than four minutes long.